# Are there good reasons for someone who publishes a survey to not release their survey questions?

Tags: interpretation, survey

I recently came across a survey that claimed to measure how closely a certain group of people adhere to a certain worldview, and I was interested in learning more about it. I emailed them to ask about it, and they autoreplied saying "The survey questions are not publicly available." They also do not publicly outline their "correct" answers for the worldview they wish to test.

My instinct is to think that they're hiding something, but...maybe not. Are there good reasons to withhold the questions and methodology and only release their conclusions? Is it more common to be able to access questions or more common for survey administrators to hold them back?

Comment: If the questions are not publicly available, then any claims about the survey should be dismissed by anyone not privy to the questions.  Period.  It's not worth your time to bother with that kind of garbage.

Comment: @whuber That's my gut instinct on this, but I'm trying to approach this in good faith here.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the easy answer here (mentioned in the comments) is to assume they're operating in bad faith, and with the subject matter you referenced, that seems especially possible. THAT BEING SAID, I'm a survey researcher with a private firm. Sometimes we don't release our survey questions if they're proprietary. In the example you mentioned, the company might have developed some specialized formula they use to assess worldview and they don't just want to give that away. Generally, I don't find this style of research super ethical or trustworthy, but industry is very different than academia, and when there's money involved you have reasonable incentives to protect how you do your research. An example of this is the [Prophet Brand Relevance Index](https://www.prophet.com/relevantbrands-2021/).

Comment: (+1) This is fair. We want the information in order to build trust and look for errors, they quite reasonably want it private to make money. There are other paths towards trust, though they are harder: if a proprietary measure/instrument was shown to be strongly predictive of something we cared about, or was strongly correlated with some other well-understood instrument, it would merit at least some careful consideration instead of dismissal.

Comment: Thanks for this perspective. To confirm, you're saying that competitive advantage, and therefore money, is the only real reason why private firms keep their methodology private?

Comment: I don't know if I'd say it's the "only" reason. It's certainly the only ethical reason I can think of (there are plenty of malevolent reasons potentially). Your survey questions are IP. You may want to determine how they're used and in what circumstances. Money is often the reason for protecting IP, but there could be other ones as well.

@mkt you're totally correct here. Prophet (the example I used above) can keep its method secret because they have a very strong reputation and history in the industry. Would be harder for orgs with less reputation to do the same.